# Open Messages with Custom Message Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, background

I want to open imessage from my app and have the text field populated with "share my app..." ( the message field at the bottom , not the phone number field)

I can open messages from my app using this line of code:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "sms:")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

But I have no idea how to pass a message with it. Is it possible to do this instead of using MFMessageComposeViewController() ? I cant use this for background play issue reasons I am experiencing , Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Very similar to @Kuldeep's response

```
let sms: String = "sms:+1234567890&body=Hello Abc How are You I am ios developer."
    let strURL: String = sms.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL.init(string: strURL)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Seemed to do the trick for me , thanks alot Kuldeep for helping me this far ; )

Answer (score 4):

Try below steps to send text on iMessage

1. Implement `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate`
2. Add below code in you button action

   ```
   if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {

           let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()

           controller.body = "Your Text here"
           controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
           controller.recipients = []
           self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

       }
   ```
3. Implement below method of `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate`

   ```
   func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {

       controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

Comment: I prefer this solution as it keeps you in the app as opposed to opening Messages and kicking you out to that.

Comment: Don't forget to add ```import MessageUI```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
let sms: String = "sms:+1234567890&body=Hello Abc How are You I am ios developer."
UIApplication.shared.open(URL.init(string: sms.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: I just copy/pasted this... didn't work on real device unfortunately @Kuldeep

Comment: @Zack117, not possible, I already tested in real device and it works perfectly.

Comment: Did u add anything to your info.plist ? @Kuldeep

Comment: @Zack117, try to create new project and paste this code in `viewDidLoad`, it works fine.

Comment: will do.. I have it on button press this is very strange ( called from #selector action )

Comment: Ran in view did load on blank project xcode 9.3 did not work :( how is this possible ??? @Kuldeep

Comment: @Zack117 It doesn't matter that you use this code in `viewDidLoad` or on `button` action Follow this Link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/dkq1ev9pt128w9b/Demo.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Zack117 I used `xCode 9.2` let me try to execute this on `xCode 9.3`

Comment: I ran the demo on my iphone6 ( real device ) and iphone 8 plus simulator and it didnt work @Kuldeep

Comment: @Kuldeep How do I send the message to a list of phone numbers in Contacts?